# Service runs tasks on an interval; should it be its own process?

Tags: android, service, process

I'm creating a service that runs in the background. It does the following:

- Gathers the user's data (with permission)
- Runs certain tasks every X minutes, and sends this data to a server every Y minutes
- I'd like if other people could write their own UI, widgets and other cool stuff.

Currently, the service continues to run between task runs/network sends (without a wakelock).

The service listens for validation and runtime changes; this requires a separate process. There are ways around this but they would involve using IPC (which I don't think would cause a big performance hit).

Questions:

- Should the service be allowed to die between tasks or should I let it run without a wakelock?
- Is it more effective to remain alive than to open a database every minute or so?
- Can people use my service if it's not in a separate process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question the arises, should my service be in it's own process?

No. By which I mean it should run in the same process as all your other components.

> I think it'd be nice if other people could write their own UI, widgets and other cool stuff.
>   It doesn't have to be in a separate process for this right?

No. It will automatically be in a separate process from the code from the "other people".

> Right now the service stays running between task runs/network sends (not keeping a wakelock though) as I figure it will be more effective than opening a database/doing setup every minute or so.

Your users may disagree with this plan. Everlasting services are the reason why users attack developers with task killers and force-stops from the Settings app.

> Should it be allowed to die between or should I let it run without a wakelock?

I recommend that you use an `IntentService` (since you need the background thread anyway for the network I/O) and let the service shut down in between polls. Also, please allow the user to control the values of X and Y from your opening paragraph.

> Tasks run on an interval, should my service die in between (having to reopen the DB)?

Generally, yes. Opening the database takes a very small amount of time (e.g., handful of milliseconds), unless the flash storage is busy. That is a small price to pay to avoid complaints from users about your service running all of the time.

> Can people use my service if it's not in a separate process?

Yes, so long as you are exposing some API (AIDL, documented set of `Intents` to send as commands via `startService()`, etc.).

Comment: Doesn't the worker threads die when the service is killed? I have long running tasks and I want to be able to handle other things while those are running which is why I haven't used IntentService so far.

Comment: @Nicklas A.: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: If I spawn a worker thread from the onHandleIntent will that thread die when the service is shut down, I though it was pretty clear... This problem occurs since intent service cannot handle multiple intents concurrently.

Comment: @Nicklas A.: You should never "spawn a worker thread from the onHandleIntent". "This problem occurs since intent service cannot handle multiple intents concurrently" -- correct. You are welcome to make your own `ConcurrentIntentService` or some such. Regardless, the service should shut down when the work is complete.

Comment: This will mean a lot more work since I currently keep stuff in memory up to a limit when I flush to the DB. Will having the service be running but be idle really make such a difference?

Comment: @Nicklas A.: Users do not care about "idle". In their eyes, you are wasting RAM and harming their device. Boards are full of complaints from users about moronic developers who have services running all the time. More importantly, because of said moronic developers, Android will be killing off your service whether you like it or not -- it's down to about 30 minutes before a service will get on the queue to be killed due to old age.

Comment: Not if I put it in the foreground, the user should be aware that the service is running. I need to put a notification while it's running so I cannot kill the service or the notif will go away.

Comment: That is usually only used for things that the *user* thinks belong in the foreground (e.g., music players). If your app fits that model, fine.

Comment: I am actively gathering potentially sensitive data from the users phone, the user should be made aware that the app is running at all time. It is more of a privacy issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it might be worth dedicating an app purely to the service (i.e., no other components except a 'settings' Activity) and do everything through Intents.

As long as the manifest has all possible Intents registered using `<intent-filter>` blocks, anyone can communicate with it (your own apps as well as any 3rd party apps).

Also, you might want to use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which will process commands as they arrive and then shut itself down when finished.

Without fully understanding your requirements, i.e., what exactly the service is processing, it's difficult to advise further.

Comment: Users tend not to like apps with no activities. We see this a lot with app-widget-only apps -- users complain the app is "broken" because they don't see an icon for it in the launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Actually I agree with you and I've edited my answer to include a 'settings' Activity. My reasoning was that Niklas mentioned other people developing their own add-ons and, as such, he would be dealing with 'techie' users who wouldn't necessarily think the app was 'broken' because there wasn't a launcher presence. I still think a minimalist approach could work but a 'settings' Activity would make sense.

Comment: Well, we have our own UI as well